# htaccess add redirect exception RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

here is my htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

what I am trying to do is to add an exception for the folder stat that way when I try to open it it doesn't redirect me to the home page.
any suggestions/help please  ?

Comment: You need to be clearer. What is an example of a URL which should be in your exclusion? Is `stat` a directory? Is it at the document root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `I am trying to do is to add an exception for the folder stat`

You can try this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(public|stat)/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```